# Sum values in multiple columns that have the same title

Tags: excel

Assume I have the following table, where column title (S1,S1,S2,...) may have more than one column with same name:

```
Type/Step       S1  S1  S2  S2  S2  S3
Type A          1   3   6   7   2   2
Type B          4   4   5   3   1   2
Type C          5   4   3   2   2   3
```

I have another table:

```
Item    Type    Step    TOTAL
Item 1  Type A  S1      ?
Item 2  Type B  S2      ?
Item 3  Type C  S3      ?
```

Sum value in all same steps that match Type and Step given?

Comment: Basically: =SUMPRODUCT((first_column=Item)*(first_row=Step)*table_values) adjusting ranges to match your data.

Answer (score 1):

I would do a pivot table but the way you organize your data is not the most optimal.

So, an array function should do the job.
To validate the array function you need to use CTRL + MAJ + ENTRY 
For example, for cell D7 in my example, copy the formula =SUM(IF($B$1:$G$1=C7,B2:G2)) in the formula bar and ress CTRL + MAJ + ENTRY. 
The just drag down the formula, it will work.

[image: example of array function]